# How to iterate this JSON object and output each item as a table header?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, handlebars.js

I have a JSON object that is like this:

```
 {
   "title": {
     "items": [ "student" , "school" , "year" , "program" , "age"  ]
   } 
 }
```

I would like to iterate each item and put each of them in a  tag through handlebars. I have tried to use

```
    {{title.items}}
```

But apparently this takes everything in items as one string. What's the best way to break each part down?

Comment: `title.items.forEach(function() {  ...`

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsbin.com/xajenunu/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#each`, e.g.:

```
{{#each title.items}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

See docs: http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration

Comment: When I do this, it returns "cannot GET localhost xxx"

Comment: That doesn't look like an error from Handlebars. Are you sure your server is running?